# How do I avoid API calls are cached?

Tags: 8

I'm using Drupal 8 in headless mode with Angular 8 as my client, but Drupal caches the API calls. For example, I have an end point which suppose to give items in random order, but this doesn't happen. I only get cache items in a particular order.

How can I overcome this? I have tried to disable the cache modules, but I still get the same behavior.

Answer (score 15):

There are two level of caching in Drupal.

**1.) Dynamic Page Cache**

You have to provide the correct cache metadata on the json response.

For example use the cache properties from a config or content entity

```
$response->addCacheableDependency($entitiy);
```

or build a cacheable metadata object and add this to the response:

```
$build = [
  '#cache' => [
    'contexts' => ['url.query_args'],
    'tags' => ['node:1', 'node_list'],
    'max-age' => 300,
  ],
];
$cache_metadata = \Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray($build);
$response->addCacheableDependency($cache_metadata);
```

You can use this in a custom controller or implement this in an event subscriber to alter responses from other modules (core or contrib).

**2.) Internal Page Cache**

The module *Internal Page Cache* caches all responses for anonymous requests regardless of the cache metadata. You can uninstall this module to disable this cache.

**Alternative solution**

On the client side append a different query string on every request to get a fresh response:

```
node/123?_format=json&time=123456789
```

This will disable the *Internal Page Cache* and parts of the *Dynamic Page Cache*.

Reference: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/javascript-and-drupal-8-restful-web-services

Comment: You can also disable Internal Page Cache for specific routes with \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger(); And if https://www.drupal.org/node/2352009 gets in, it will also respect the max-age.

Comment: I had to add Berdir's suggestion of \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger(); otherwise it still cached for anonymous users for me

Comment: I found that drupal-8 only used the path component as cache key. I was using get query parameters but always getting the same result regardless of what was in the parameter. The time get parameter would not work.

Comment: @Interlated, for response (page) caching there are two levels as described. Level 2 builds cache keys based on the entire URL including the query string. Level 1 builds cache keys based on routes + contexts. See the code example.

Comment: If the time parameter is in seconds you probably want to disable caching in level 1 by adding cache max-age of 0. Doesn't make much sense to add a new cache entry every 1 second.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to disable cache entirely for my endpoints. You can do it adding a cacheable dependency with a zero MaxAge  to the *ResourceResponse* object.

Here is an example:

```
$response = new ResourceResponse($data);
$disable_cache = new CacheableMetadata();
$disable_cache->setCacheMaxAge(0);

$response->addCacheableDependency($disable_cache);

return $response;
```

Comment: This seems like a great idea for development, but for a production site you would want to add the parameters that might vary the response to your `addCacheableDependency` so that your site can be more performant/scalable.