# How to uncache jsonapi?

Tags: 8

As usual, I am debugging something and this time, it's jsonapi. I already have `$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';` and `$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';` this works for HTML, how do you force JSONAPI to not cache?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drupal 8 caches Rest API Calls](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222467/drupal-8-caches-rest-api-calls)

Comment: Unlikely this has something to do with HTML/JSON, but you need to disable 3 cache bins now, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/248194/twig-cache-wont-disable

Comment: @leymannx no, it does not, and it is not helpful at all, in fact _that_ should be closed in favor of _this_ one because that one predates https://www.drupal.org/node/2896679 which was my problem. It's very likely I was not bitten by the separate page cache bin normally because I am typically logged in the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the internal page cache and Internal dynamic page cache, Drupal will heavily cache all GET requests, so what you are missing is

```
$settings['cache']['bins']['page'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

as the 3rd bin to clear but this won't work due to dynamic cache, so can you either manually purge the entire Drupal cache or set a timestamp into your URL so you can bypass caching for development.

```
node/1?_format=json&time=123456789
```

Comment: AH. The reason for confusion lies in "Disable the render cache (this includes the page cache)." the `(this includes the page cache)` part was added in http://drupal.org/i/606840 very very long ago to `sites/example.settings.local.php` and removed in http://drupal.org/i/2921706 in 2018 January and my settings.local.php significantly predates that.